# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes (Python 3 vs Python 2 )

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The below code works perfectly for python 2.7.13

```
import os
with open('random.bin','w') as f:
    f.write(os.urandom(10))
```

But throws error for python 3 
3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/hsingh/PycharmProjects/Item3.py", line 3, in
>   
>       f.write(os.urandom(10)) TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Any reason why there is difference in behaviour or how to fix this

Comment: `f.write(str(os.urandom(10)))` works for me

Comment: @JacobIRR which version of python you are using?

Comment: `>>> sys.version
'3.6.1...'`

Comment: Same error I got in online compiler http://rextester.com/l/python3_online_compiler

Comment: I'm sure you'll find plenty of ways to fix this by googling "python write bytes to file"

Comment: @jonatan That's what I am doing now :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In Python 3 it makes a difference whether you open the file in binary or text mode. Just add the `b` flag to make it binary:

```
with open('random.bin','wb') as f:
```

This works in Python 2 too.