# Python - TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've got an error message from python.
It's a code that extracts phonetic symbols from the oxford online dictionary.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Download\Oxford_PhoneticSymbol\Oxford_PhoneticSymbol.py", line 24,
>   in 
>       fw.write((result + "\n").encode("utf-8")) TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Original source is from; https://my.oschina.net/sfshine/blog/3076588

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open('./words.txt')
fw = open('./result.txt','a')

line = f.readline()
index = 0
while line:
    index = index+1
    url = "https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/" + line.strip()
    print(str(index) + ":" + url)
    wbdata = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36'}).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(wbdata,'html.parser')
    news_titles = soup.select("span.pron-g > span.phon")
    # print(news_titles)
    result = ''
    for n in news_titles:   
        title = n.get_text()    
        if 'NAmE' in title:
            result += '['+title.replace('NAmE','').replace('//','') + ']'
    print(result)  
    fw.write((result + "\n").encode("utf-8"))
    line = f.readline()
    time.sleep(0.1)

fw.close()
f.close()
```

Like it needed, I have put two txt files in the same directory.
And I filled a few words in words.txt and made the result.txt as blank, but I got the error.

```
(words.txt, saved as UTF-8)
source
technic
resource
power
box
created
computer
charged
learned
```

**Any Idea how to fix this?**

Comment: have you tried to change your open,   fw = open('./result.txt','a') from 'a' to 'ab'

Comment: What did you think you did when you wrote `(result + "\n").encode("utf-8")`? The error message is very clear about what's going on, are you familiar with bytes vs strings? edit: scratch that, i see that you're copying a tutorial, that is giving a pretty sad example of how people mix up bytes and strings.

Comment: @ChristianSloper I have just tried to change a to ab, and it worked, but missed few.   thanks for your advice.    *source  (none) / technic (none, it doesn't exist on oxford) / resource   [ˈriːsɔːrs][rɪˈsɔːrs] / power      [ˈpaʊər] / box        [bɑːks] / created (none) / computer   [kəmˈpjuːtər] / charged    [tʃɑːrdʒd] / learned    [ˈlɜːrnɪd][lɜːrnd]

Comment: You have a link in this question which is misleading. It currently displays one URL, but actually links to another URL. Please [edit] your question so the URL which is displayed is the same as the URL the link actually links to. This is probably just a formatting error, but it's not clear which URL you are actually wanting to be linking to, so I didn't just repair it.

Comment: Ooops, thanks for comment. Link has been fixed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes (Python 3 vs Python 2 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47027254/typeerror-write-argument-must-be-str-not-bytes-python-3-vs-python-2)

Answer (score 13):

The solution to this error when saving a downloaded page to file:

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

is:

```
fw = open('./result.txt','wb')
```

"b" for binary makes the difference.

Comment: Thank you for this. OMG  I'm trying to learn this alien language. So which one should I change or where to put    outFile = open('output.xml', 'wb')  <--- this into?

Comment: I've changed  fw = open('./result.txt','a')  to  outFile = open('output.xml', 'wb')   and I got error again. fw.write((result + "\n").encode("utf-8"))
NameError: name 'fw' is not defined. How to define line 24?

Comment: use `fw = open('./result.txt','wb') `

Comment: Oh, I got better result, but still not perfect. Thanks anyway.

Comment: When I tried to write bytes, there is a new blank line after every bytes line.