# pexpect.interact(): TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect

My pexpect script is q**uite simple, but I hit "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes**" after `child.interact()`

```
child = pexpect.spawn('npm login', timeout=40, encoding='utf-8')
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout
child.expect('Username:')
child.sendline('qiulang2000')
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline('xxxx')
...
child.interact()
```

The error message:

```
File "/Users/qiulang/PycharmProjects/pexpect-test/./main.py", line 63, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/qiulang/PycharmProjects/pexpect-test/./main.py", line 59, in main
    npm_login()
  File "/Users/qiulang/PycharmProjects/pexpect-test/./main.py", line 54, in npm_login
    child.interact()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 793, in interact
    self.__interact_copy(escape_character, input_filter, output_filter)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 838, in __interact_copy
    self._log(data, 'read')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 133, in _log
    second_log.write(s)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

I know what that error meant, e.g. as [TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes (Python 3 vs Python 2 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47027254/typeerror-write-argument-must-be-str-not-bytes-python-3-vs-python-2) explained, but how do I fix that for `child.interact()` ?

I change my codes to

```
child = pexpect.spawn('npm login', timeout=40)
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout.buffer
...
```

BUT then pexpect echo **twice** for every message after `interact()`! How do I fix that then ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67048674/double-characters-while-do-interact-using-pexpect/67052397

Comment: Thanks child.logfile_read = None not only solved duplicated echo but also write() argument must be str, not bytes!

Answer (score 1):

The comment I got solved my two problems. I listed what I experienced but all credits go to him.

So after add `child.logfile_read = None`  it solved the "**TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes**" error with using `child.logfile_read = sys.stdout`.

It also solved the **duplicated echo** problem when using `child.logfile_read = sys.stdout.buffer`

To quote from [pexpect.interact](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html?highlight=interact#pexpect.spawn.interact) doc, "If a logfile is specified, then the data sent and received from the child process in interact mode is **duplicated to the given log**" and "Even with encoding='utf-8' support, meth:interact will always pass input_filter and output_filter bytes.", which probably explained the TypeError I got.

BTW, for a simple pexpect script like `ssh login` I actually don't need to set `child.logfile_read = sys.stdout` at all because I just need to send my ssh password. But for `npm login` because it needs several steps, without `child.logfile_read = sys.stdout` the script will fail.